# Setprecision is Confusing

Tags: c++

I just want to ask about setprecision because I'm a bit confused.

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
  double rate = x;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << rate;
}
```

where x = to following:

the left side of equation are the values of x.

1.105 = 1.10 should be 1.11

1.115 = 1.11 should be 1.12

1.125 = 1.12 should be 1.13

1.135 = 1.14 which is correct

1.145 = 1.15 also correct

but if x is:

2.115 = 2.12 which is correct

2.125 = 2.12 should be 2.13

so why in a certain value it's correct but sometimes it's wrong?

please enlighten me. thanks

Comment: It appears that `fixed` is using [banker’s rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). No idea whether this can be controlled. If you don’t find any other fix, you may need to round manually before formatting.

Comment: but setprecision is quite easy and time saving method because it can format all the outputs to two decimal places unlike manual formatting that i should format each. 

for example :
i need to format the output for double rate,rate1,rate2,rate3,rate4 to two decimal places, i will just use setprecision once to format each of them.

Answer (score 8):

There is no reason to expect that any of the constants in your post can be represented *exactly* using the floating-point system. As a consequence, the exact halves that you have may no longer be exact halves once you store them in a `double` variable (regardless of how the iostreams are meant to round such numbers.)

The following code illustrates my point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
  double rate = 1.115;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(20) << rate;
}
```

Output:

```
1.11499999999999999112
```

I would recommend taking a look at the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.16).

Comment: Your answer doesn’t apply here. The OP’s issue is formatting induced rounding, not floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: formatting-induced rounding may be playing a part, but in my view it's not the main issue.

Comment: @aix Except that 1.125 is exactly representable and also is "wrong" according to the OP.

Comment: @Mark B: I am not disputing that. What I am saying is that the OP's expectation that exact halves should be handled in a certain consistent manner is entirely misplaced.

Comment: so what should i do as an alternative to setprecision? what i want is to format all the outputs to two decimal places, rounding them up if the 3rd number on the right of the decimal is 5 and up. for example: 1.105 will result in 1.11. should i use manual formating of each outputs?

Comment: @aix Format induced rounding starts with the actual value in the floating point variable.  Which in no case will be 1.105.  After that, a quality implementation of `<<(double)` will respect the current rounding mode of the processor.  Which, by default, gives 1.30 for 1.25 (round to even).

Comment: @MarcQuebrarTan you can add a delta on the float number.like this 1.105+0.0000001,then the result must be 1.11

Answer (score 2):

Some of the numbers you're printing may not be representable as a floating point number and may actually be lower or higher than you think, directly affecting the rounding.

Since you're trying to format a floating point number to fixed point, have you considered actually USING a fixed point number (int/long scaled by say 1000 depending on your needs) that has its own insert operator defined? Then you'll always get accurate display and rounding without needing to rely on `setprecision` having any particular behavior (I couldn't find the relevant conversion section in the standard in a quick look).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say that 1.105 should be 1.11?  The C++ standard says
nothing about it, but the default rounding mode on most of the
usual machines (Intel, Sparc, etc.) is round to even, so 1.105
should be 1.10.  In general, when the exact result is exactly
between two representable values, the rule is to round to the
one with an even least significant digit.

I also wonder where you're getting these values.  On the usual
machines, 1.105 can't be represented, so you have something
slightly larger or slightly smaller.

And of course, the above comments apply for all of the other
values you've cited.

Comment: According to the OP 1.115 rounded to 1.11 which isn't even.

Comment: so what should i do as an alternative to setprecision? what i want is to format all the outputs to two decimal places, rounding them up if the 3rd number on the right of the decimal is 5 and up. for example: 1.105 will result in 1.11. should i use manual formating of each outputs?

Comment: @Mark B.  That's true.  Most likely, my second point (that he never had 1.105 or 1.115 to begin with) is the true explination.  But given his expectations, I thought that some remarks concerning round to even were in order.

Comment: @Marc If you really need true bankers rounding, you'll probably have to find a decimal class, and do decimal arithmetic.  On the systems I know, there are means of changing the rounding mode, but they still won't address the fact that you don't have 1.105 or 1.115 to begin with.

Comment: @James But round to even is almost never a useful result, unless you work in finances (and then you wouldn’t be using floating point numbers). The usual rule for rounding is different.

Comment: @Konrad I think you got it backwards.  Finance is about the only place round to even is not the most appropriate---in finance, you have to round according to what the local laws require (which usually means decimal anyway).  In any normal mathematical work, however, round to even is preferred to avoid any bias in the rounding.

Comment: @James Not according to what I thought, and Wikipedia is with me on this: “This is widely used in bookkeeping” (but it also says that this is the default in IEEE 754). I’ve never seen it used in science, or indeed anywhere else.

Comment: If the Wikipedia says that round to even is widely used in bookkeeping, it's wrong.  It's illegal to use round to even in bookkeeping, at least in Europe.  (There's a reason banker's rounding is known as banker's rounding.)  On the other hand, round to even is definitely the prefered rounding in any numerical work, see "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithmetic", particularly the section "Exactly Rounded Operations".